# Can Laravel Shopping Cart Work with Paypal?

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart

I wanted to use Laravel Shopping Cart, but I'm not sure how well it works with Paypal.
Does anyone know?

https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any built in implementation in the core, however you can ask the question in their github repo or check if there are any plugins.

There are many alternatives out there with paypal integration and it's not hard to do it yourself, doing a quick search using your favorite search engine will give you a few suggestions on how to approach this. I personally prefer Stripe because it's even more developer friendly.

If you want to build your own cart, there's even a comprehensive guide on how to do it: [Build a Laravel shopping cart](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51qUXDyBqx0mKVOhLNFwwxvH)

Answer (score 0):

Reading LaravelShoppingCart documentation, it seems this plugin does not manage any payment method, only the cart (Add, remove, total, etc).

If you're interested in payment methods, you should look at [Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/master/billing).

Edit : Cashier uses [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) or [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com).

Apparently, [Stripe cannot work with Paypal](https://www.quora.com/Can-customers-pay-with-PayPal-via-Stripes-API), but as Braintree belongs to Paypal, [this seems easily doable](https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-fr/payment-methods/accept-paypal).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented on avored laravel full e commerce with admin panel. Give it a try and let me know if you face any bug or any feedback is welcome. As of now it’s in development so it’s not stable yet.

https://github.com/avored